# IDL equivalent of python's dir()

Tags: idl, envi

In python, `dir(X)` will list the attributes and methods of object X. Is there something similar for an IDL object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a command. But in the IDE command line, typing "x." and then hovering your mouse over it will show you what attributes and functions are associated with it.